# Synchronous Ajax in a Loop - Issues with Blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of object-ids and need to send each one to the backend for processing. Backend processing is time intensive, resource intensive, and prone to failure. Hence, I would like each item processed one at a time with the results of the backend processing rendered on the browser.

My code is as follows (simplified for easy reading):

```js
// initialize variables:
var items = ['obj-1', 'obj-2', 'obj-3', ...],
var messageBoard = $('#message-board-id');

// append start message to board:
messageBoard.append('Starting backend job');

// iterate over each item:
for (var item of items) {

  // send sync ajax request:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'backend_process_url/',
    type : 'POST',
    aysnc : false,
    data : {
      item : item,
    },
    
    // handle successful backend jobs:
    success : function(response) {
      messageBoard.append('Job successful!');
      ...
    }  

    // handle failed backend jobs:
    error : function(response) {
      messageBoard.append('Job failed!');
      ...
    }
  }

}

messageBoard.append('All jobs complete');
```

The issue is that the sync ajax request holds up the entire loop - meaning no messages are appended to the `messageBoard` until all backend jobs are complete. The desired behavior is that messages are displayed as backend jobs for each item are finished.

My understanding of promises is limited and attempts at using them have failed - if this is a plausible solution, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `aysnc : false` does?  If you want them one after the other you should implement them in an ajax queue.

Comment: Thanks - any chance you can demonstrate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the next Ajax request was initiated on `success` of the first?

You would have to place the Ajax code inside a named function so you can call it again on `success`. You even can insert a delay in between each requests (Here I used 800ms). The key is to check the *"job"* index compared to the `items` length.

Here is an example using [JSON PlaceHolder.com](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/)... Where the responses are obtained super quickly. But try that with your longer requests. I'm pretty sure it will work fine.

```js
// initialize variables:
var items = [{userId:1},{userId:3},{userId:5},{userId:7},{userId:9}];
var messageBoard = $('#message-board-id');

function runAjax(reqIndex=0){

  // send async Ajax request:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type : 'POST',
    data : items[reqIndex],

    // handle successful backend jobs:
    success : function(response) {
      messageBoard.append(`Job #${reqIndex} successful!<br>`);
      console.log(`Job #${reqIndex}`,response)

      // Get the next index if still lees than the items length
      reqIndex = (reqIndex >= items.length-1) ? null : reqIndex+1
      
      // If not null
      if(reqIndex){
        setTimeout(runAjax(reqIndex),800)
      }else{
        messageBoard.append('All jobs complete');
      }
    },
    // handle failed backend jobs:
    error : function(response) {
      messageBoard.append('Job failed!');
    }
  })
}

// append start message to board:
messageBoard.append('Starting backend job<br>');

// Start with the first request to make, using the index 0 of the items array.
runAjax()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message-board-id"></div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks - seems like it should work - I'll try and implement and mark as accepted if there are no issues.